# Spring Roo gives build error for maven in STS

Tags: maven-2, spring-roo

I am using STS for spring roo project. when i execute command i get the following error

> Build errors for articles;
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException:
>   Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.0:compile
>   (default) on project articles:
>   Execution default of goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.0:compile
>   failed: Plugin
>   org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.0
>   or one of its dependencies could not
>   be resolved: The following artifacts
>   could not be resolved:
>   org.aspectj:aspectjtools:jar:1.6.11.M1,
>   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1:
>   The repository system is offline but
>   the artifact
>   org.aspectj:aspectjtools:jar:1.6.11.M1
>   is not available in the local
>   repository.`

My internet is working fine. other dependencies download fine but not above one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where this funny version comes from, but it's certainly not to be found in Maven Central:

[`org.aspectj:aspectjtools` versions](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/aspectj/aspectjtools/)

you can do a `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.aspectj` to see where the dependency is coming from and then set the dependency version to the current version (1.6.10).

But apart from that,

> The repository system is offline

this sounds like a needed repository was not available. Maybe a server is / was down, the error doesn't have to be on your side.

Comment: i am working in STS and have not installed maven separately . where can i run the above maven command. is there is maven console like roo terminal to run command. also will that command is for current project or all projects

Answer (score 0):

You may hitting [this bug](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-1111), based on the version of STS/Spring Roo that you are using.  If so, the fix is present in this [comment](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-1111?focusedCommentId=56375&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_56375).